# How to auto change repeat date in same month to end date of previous month

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have list of date of installment payments from the same person and amount in column A (date), C (name) and D (amount)

```
12/1/2017                   Ali                  $500
2/3/2017                    Ali                  $500
25/3/2017                   Ali                  $500
21/4/2017                   Ali                  $500
2/6/2017                    Ali                  $500
28/6/2017                   Ali                  $500
```

How do I put a formula in column B to use the same date in column A for 12/1/2017, 25/3/2017, 21/4/2017 and 28/6/2017 (because each date represent only one month) but to change the date 2/3/2017 to 28/2/2017 (previous month end)  and 2/6/2017 to 31/5/2017 (previous month end) because 2/3/2017 should represent payment in February and 2/6/2017 should represent payment in May.

I need to use a formula, not a pivot table, because I need to auto change any more than one date in the same month such as 2/3/2017 and 2/6/2017 in my example.

Comment: Do you have Excel 2007 or above? There's an EOMONTH function in higher versions of Excel that can simplify the solution. I surely know it's present in Excel 2013. It may appear that you have mixed dd/mm/yy and mm/dd/yy format. Stick to one format for effective solution. Best option is to use dd-mmm-yyyy format for date.

Comment: Are you expecting that if there are dates with repeat months, then it should fall back to previous month end for such dates? If yes, this may affect the already existing data if you change it later and two dates fall in the same month. Then both will change to previous month end. Will that be correct?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear where your "cut off" is, but imagining it's the 10th, and imagining your first date is in cell A1, you can use the formula: `=IF(DAY(A1)<10,A1-DAY(A1),A1)`